# Watson Assistant: Message Bubble spacing (margin-bottom) in Chrome not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I embedded a Watson Chatbot to my site using the Watson Assistant plug-in for WordPress.
I haven't touched anything regarding the CSS styling of the bot.

Every message bubble sent gets by default a 10px `margin-bottom`, that's is how the spacing works.

On Firefox, Safari, and Opera everything looks fine. Just on Chrome the last message sent by Watson doesn't get any spacing from the text input. Why is that? Changing the margin or e.g. adding padding to the message container (wrapper) doesn't work.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

This is Chrome. As you can see the margin is there, it just doesn't have any effect.

[image: Chrome]

This is Firefox representing the other browsers where everything is normal.

[image: Firefox]

Comment: The fact that the other browsers see the Margin, and that its even shown in the css for chrome, but not being actioned makes me think this is a chrome bug, rather then with the web chat code.

Comment: @timd mhm okay.. so there is nothing I could do about this? Cause yea with my css styling it really looks awful

Comment: I see the same thing on my website, and I agree - look like a Chrome issue rather than the Watson plug-in. Have you tried e-mailing the plug-in support people? https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/conversation-watson/